# Round Brackets around a For Loop

Tags: python

In Python, round brackets around my if statement condition like so is perfectly valid:

```
In [0]: test = 3
   ...: if (test == 3):
   ...:     print('ya') 
ya
```

Why do round brackets around the for-loop body in the following example give a syntax error?

```
In [1]: my_list = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: for (item in my_list):
   ...:     print(item)
  File "<ipython-input-1->", line 1
    for (item in my_list):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Because it's a syntax error.

Comment: Because they don't make sense they way you're using them. You are free to use parentheses around the iterator expression, e.g., `for item in ([x for list in mylist if x > 2]):`. But there is no syntax that matches `for <expression>`.

Comment: @j_krl  programming languages have valid syntax and invalid syntax, all other answers will be a longer version of 'because that's not how you write a for statement'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arbitrary (named) expression (such as `(test == 3)`) follows the `if` keyword.

```
if_stmt:
    | 'if' named_expression ':' block elif_stmt 
    | 'if' named_expression ':' block [else_block]
```

An arbitrary expression does *not* follow the `for` keyword. Only a valid *target* can follow the keyword, and that target is followed by the keyword `in`, which is followed by an arbitrary ("star") expression.

```
for_stmt:
    | 'for' star_targets 'in' ~ star_expressions ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block [else_block] 
    | ASYNC 'for' star_targets 'in' ~ star_expressions ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block [else_block]
```

(Both excerpts from the grammar can be found in the [Full Grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).)

---

The OP deleted a comment indicating they were looking to use parentheses for implicit line continuation. However, both the target and the iterable expression can be parenthesized, allowing implicit continuation in either part. Only the `in` keyword forces explicit line continuation. For example, you could rewrite

```
for x, y \
     in \
    zip(foo, bar):
```

as

```
for (x,
     y) in zip(foo,
               bar):
```

if you really wanted to. Allow the entire `... in ...` to be parenthesized would complicate the grammar while only adding the ability to break the line in two additional places.

(More abstractly, you can parenthesize both sides of the `in` keyword, so

```
for (...) in (...):
```

can become

```
for (
     ...
    ) in (
          ...
         ):
```

The only place you *need* explicit continuation would be in the minimal 5-character string `) in (` in the middle.
)

Comment: The obvious follow-up question is *why* is the grammar specified this way?

Comment: Why would you go out of your way to allow unnecessary parentheses in a way that complicates parsing? For example, `for (x) in [1,2,3]: ...` is legal because `(x)` is a legal target, whether or not the parentheses are useful. `for ... in ...` is an syntactic construct all its own, and there's no useful reason for allowing optional parentheses in the rule.

Comment: Right well that's why I made the point that there is a use case for parentheses when doing e.g. chained operator comparisons. Obvious to you I'm sure, but perhaps not the OP ;)

Comment: @j_krl It sounds like you want a generator expression of list comphrension instead

Comment: I'll add as a comment, because my parser knowledge is rusty, that allowing `for (x in y)` might also make Python's grammar no longer be LL(1), as you can no longer tell if the `(` is the start of a parenthesized target or the start of a parenthesized target/iterator pair without lookahead. It is something you could do with an LR(1) grammar, but parsers for LR(1) grammars are both less efficient and harder to implement than parsers for LL(1) grammars. (This may be less of an issue going forward, because Python now uses a PEG grammar rather than a LL(1) grammar to define the language.)

Comment: It was a good comment. I wasn't thinking about line continuation, but then I realized that adding parentheses around the entire thing only adds a tiny benefit compared to the effort of supporting the syntax in the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the pedantic answer is this is how the language is specified. Perhaps a more practical answer is `(test == 3)` is more relevant when doing multiple comparisons because of chained comparisons and operator precidence etc., e.g.

```
>>> 1 == 2 == False
False
>>> (1 == 2) == False
True
```

Answer (score -1):

Think about what you're actually doing with the second example.

The syntax for a `for` loop is

```
for variable_name in iterable
```

If you add parentheses:

```
for (variable_name in iterable):
```

then the expression `variable_name in iterable` gets resolved, because parentheses come first in order of operations, and it returns a boolean, and then you have either `for False:` or `for True:`, which doesn't make sense.

(python doesn't actually evaluate this - the compiler sees it and detects that it doesn't make syntactic sense before it would need to evaluate it - but this is why it's not valid)

Comment: Nothing gets resolved, because the parser raises a `SyntaxError` immediately,

Comment: If an expression were evaluated first, something like `for (x in [1,2,3])` would raise a `NameError` before you got a `SyntaxError` for the undefined name `x`.

Comment: Wasn't thinking about the resolution order, that makes sense. Appreciate it